# How do I hide the progress bar without waiting for the entire page to load in webview?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, mobile, webview

I have a webview page in my app. Also there is a progress bar for control of load page. The progress bar working until to load all of page but I wanna hide it after the first upload. How can I do that in kotlin or java ?

Comment: Please, provide a [MCVE].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I presume that right now you have extend `WebViewClient` and you override methods `onPageStarted` and `onPageFinished` to show/hide the progress bar.

You also need to extend `WebChromeClient` and override method `onProgressChanged` so that you can hide the progress bar after the first data has started to load in the webview - if that's what you want to do, it's not very clear what you want to achieve.

To set up your classes in the WebView you use, respectively, the methods `WebView.setWebViewClient` and `WebView.setWebChromeClient`.